# Linking SDL library in a Makefile, c++

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl

I'm working on a collaborative project and the guy who controls the master branch of the project works on a mac.  Because of this, there are a few minor differences in his makefile that don't translate well to me on Windows.  I use MinGW to hold my libraries, and compile using g++.

Makefile (as I thought it should go)

```
bomb: source/Level.cpp source/Level.h source/main.cpp
g++ -o bomb source/Level.cpp source/main.cpp -Wall -I. -I\MinGW\include\SDL -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image
```

The Makefile that works for him:

```
bomb: source/Level.cpp source/Level.h source/main.cpp
g++ -o bomb source/Level.cpp source/main.cpp -Wall -I. -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Headers -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -framework
```

My include files for the SDL library are at "C:\MinGW\include\SDL".  Using that knowledge, how would I correctly write the makefile?  As a side note, the error I get when using my current makefile is:

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\src\mingwrt/../mingw/main.c:73: undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding `-lmingw32` to the end of the libraries list? And do you have a `int main(int argc, char** argv)` function defined somewhere? Also, see the [SDL FAQ](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/FAQWindows#I_get_.22Undefined_reference_to_.27WinMain.4016.27.22)

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain, very briefly, why that fixed my problem? Also, I'll accept your answer when the site lets me in about 5 minutes :)

Comment: AFAIK SDL converts the `main` function to the `WinMain` function which is in the MinGW32 runtime library. Consequently you need to link against it.

Comment: Actually libmingw32 must be first. The proper order of libs is: `-lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL ...rest`

Comment: @Yarg Yes, you're right. Anyways, it would be better to use `sdl-config --cflags --libs` instead of listing the libraries manually.